# inconsistencies while using LEAD and LAG when trying to replace null values on snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and trying to write an SQL query to replace null values with the last recorded Ip for each ID based on the date. The Id is considered to be descending and the date is also descending for each Id.

Here is an example of my table

table name: customer

| id | date | ip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 113 | 2022-02-05 11:40:42 | Null |
| 113 | 2021-12-05 11:40:42 | Null |
| 113 | 2021-08-05 11:40:42 | Null |
| 113 | 2021-07-05 11:40:42 | Null |
| 113 | 2022-02-05 11:40:42 | 83:93:225:63 |
| 112 | 2022-02-05 11:40:42 | Null |
| 112 | 2021-02-05 11:40:42 | 3:9:225:63 |
| 112 | 2020-02-05 11:40:42 | 8:9:225:63 |

what I want to achieve

| id | date | ip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 113 | 2022-02-05 11:40:42 | 83:93:225:63 |
| 113 | 2021-12-05 11:40:42 | 83:93:225:63 |
| 113 | 2021-08-05 11:40:42 | 83:93:225:63 |
| 113 | 2021-07-05 11:40:42 | 83:93:225:63 |
| 113 | 2022-02-05 11:40:42 | 83:93:225:63 |
| 112 | 2022-02-05 11:40:42 | 3:9:225:63 |
| 112 | 2021-02-05 11:40:42 | 3:9:225:63 |
| 112 | 2020-02-05 11:40:42 | 8:9:225:63 |

Comment: When you say `based on the date` for the "last ip" do you mean last IP across all time sorted by date, OR last IP prior to this row, sorted by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want the "next", "last", "prior" value, so here are all three

Edited to have the same sort order as you asked for:

```
SELECT column1 as id
    ,to_date(column2) as date
    ,column3 as ip 
    ,LAST_VALUE(ip) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) last_value
    ,NVL(ip, last_value) AS current_or_last
    ,LEAD(ip) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) as next_value
    ,NVL(ip, next_value) AS current_or_next  
    ,LAG(ip) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) as prior_value
    ,NVL(ip, prior_value) AS current_or_prior
FROM VALUES
    (113,'2022-02-05 11:40:42',null),
    (113,'2021-12-05 11:40:42',null),
    (113,'2021-08-05 11:40:42',null),
    (113,'2021-07-05 11:40:42',null),
    (113,'2022-02-05 11:40:42','83:93:225:63'),
    (112,'2022-02-05 11:40:42',null),
    (112,'2021-02-05 11:40:42','3:9:225:63'),
    (112,'2020-02-05 11:40:42','8:9:225:63')
ORDER BY 1 DESC,2 DESC;
```

gives:

| ID | DATE | IP | LAST_VALUE | CURRENT_OR_LAST | NEXT_VALUE | CURRENT_OR_NEXT | PRIOR_VALUE | CURRENT_OR_PRIOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 113 | 2022-02-05 |  | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 |  |  |
| 113 | 2022-02-05 | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 |  | 83:93:225:63 |  | 83:93:225:63 |
| 113 | 2021-12-05 |  | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 |  |  |
| 113 | 2021-08-05 |  | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 |  |  |
| 113 | 2021-07-05 |  | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 | 83:93:225:63 |  |  |
| 112 | 2022-02-05 |  | 3:9:225:63 | 3:9:225:63 |  |  | 3:9:225:63 | 3:9:225:63 |
| 112 | 2021-02-05 | 3:9:225:63 | 3:9:225:63 | 3:9:225:63 |  | 3:9:225:63 | 8:9:225:63 | 3:9:225:63 |
| 112 | 2020-02-05 | 8:9:225:63 | 3:9:225:63 | 8:9:225:63 | 3:9:225:63 | 8:9:225:63 |  | 8:9:225:63 |

Guessing you want the `current_or_last` be composed together like:

```
SELECT column1 as id
    ,to_date(column2) as date
    ,NVL(column3, LAST_VALUE(column3) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)) AS ip
FROM VALUES
    (113,'2022-02-05 11:40:42',null),
    (113,'2021-12-05 11:40:42',null),
    (113,'2021-08-05 11:40:42',null),
    (113,'2021-07-05 11:40:42',null),
    (113,'2022-02-05 11:40:42','83:93:225:63'),
    (112,'2022-02-05 11:40:42',null),
    (112,'2021-02-05 11:40:42','3:9:225:63'),
    (112,'2020-02-05 11:40:42','8:9:225:63')
ORDER BY 1 DESC,2 DESC;
```

which gives:

| ID | DATE | IP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 113 | 2022-02-05 | 83:93:225:63 |
| 113 | 2022-02-05 | 83:93:225:63 |
| 113 | 2021-12-05 | 83:93:225:63 |
| 113 | 2021-08-05 | 83:93:225:63 |
| 113 | 2021-07-05 | 83:93:225:63 |
| 112 | 2022-02-05 | 3:9:225:63 |
| 112 | 2021-02-05 | 3:9:225:63 |
| 112 | 2020-02-05 | 8:9:225:63 |

Comment: Thanks alot for your contribution, however it replaced all the null values with a single IP address. but when I replaced it with LAG, it replaced the Null with the respective IPs based on my expected output from the question

Comment: I did give you the three options on LAST_VALUE,LAG, LEAD and my answers match you expected output.

Comment: please can I have a session with you, I don't know how to put it in question.